# How to interpret this XML plan fragment?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, explain

I am looking at the query plan produced by SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm not sure I'm interpreting it properly. Examples:

```
<RelOp NodeId="2" PhysicalOp="Sort" LogicalOp="Sort" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0.0112613" 
 EstimateCPU="0.000100822" AvgRowSize="822" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.06489" Parallel="0" 
 EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0">
 ...
  <MemoryFractions Input="0.5" Output="1" />
  <RunTimeInformation>
    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10190123" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  </RunTimeInformation>
```

and

```
<RelOp NodeId="6" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" LogicalOp="Index Seek" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="1" 
 EstimateCPU="0.0502411" AvgRowSize="24" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.05024" TableCardinality="4.93715e+009" 
 Parallel="0" Partitioned="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0">
 ...
  <RunTimeInformation>
    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10190123" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  </RunTimeInformation>
```

Specifically, seeing `EstimateRows="1"` and `ActualRows="10190123"` I suspect that the optimizer incorrectly estimates the number of rows that will be processed. Subsequently, underestimated row set for the sort might lead to a major sort spill.

**Edit:**

The query in question looks similar to

```
select whatever from mytable
where integer_column1 > 848484884 and
      integer_column1 < 949494949 and
      another_int_col in (5, 8, 15, 20)
```

where the cardinality of `integer_column1` is in millions and that of `another_int_col` is a few dozen (a flag of sorts). There is a non-unique, non-clustered index on `(integer_column1, another_int_col)`. I wonder if even in the presence of updated statistics the optimizer can use the histogram/density vector of that index though.

Does my reasoning make sense?

(I don't have access to the actual system or the Management Console for that matter -- only the XML plan)

Comment: You can open the XML plan in any SSMS or SQL Sentry Plan Explorer.  But you are on track, there is discrepancy in the number of estimated rows and actual rows so you will need to update the statistics for the table

Comment: Like I said, I don't have access to any machine with SQL Server at the moment. So you seem to confirm my understanding -- these numbers do indicate that there is a discrepancy.

Comment: You can take the XML and put it in sqlsentry's PlanExplorer. That will give you much more details in a user friendly manner. If your Actual is way off than your Estimate then you have problem with Statistics. Can you confirm that your stats are up-to-date ?

Comment: @Kin -- I'm not a SQL Server guy and unfortunately I don't have any of those fancy tools -- just a text editor where I view the XML. I asked the customer I'm helping to get me the output of `dbcc show_statistics` for the index in question, but didn't see it yet.

Comment: @mustaccio plan explorer is FREE and I highly recommend using it as opposed to you viewing XML in text editor. You can refer to this article on Simple Talk -  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/managing-sql-server-statistics/

Comment: You can also just save the XML plan with an extension of `.sqlplan` and SSMS will give you the graphical display of it. Meaning you can just install SSMS (free 2012+ Express version) and open it on your own machine as `.sqlplan`.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these tools run on a Mac... Thanks for the suggestions, but the question was not about viewing the plan -- it was about interpreting it. @Kin -- the article though was rather useful.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, my original understanding was correct: the discrepancy between `EstimateRows="1"` and `ActualRows="10190123"` was an indication of incorrect optimizer estimates, caused by stale statistics (as suggested by commenters). With updated statistics the node in the plan corresponding to node 6 in the question looks like so:

```
<RelOp NodeId="25" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" LogicalOp="Index Seek" 
 EstimateRows="1.25676e+007" EstimateIO="23.8363" EstimateCPU="1.78132" AvgRowSize="24" 
 EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="25.6176" TableCardinality="4.94087e+009" Parallel="1" 
 Partitioned="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0">
...
<RunTimeInformation>
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="2" ActualRows="3457399" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="8" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="1" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="7" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="5" ActualRows="8053198" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="3" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="6" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="4" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
  <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
</RunTimeInformation>
```

Although the problem could be seen in the XML plan representation directly, for those who want a graphical representation there exist a free tool that does not require the SQL Server Management Studio, SQL Sentry Plan Explorer, or even Windows for that matter -- it is an [XSL stylesheet created by the StackOverflow user Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800473/tools-for-visualising-execution-xml-plans-as-html).

Comment: That execution plan viewer is being used on sqlfiddle.com - site that allows you to create sample tables, insert data and show and query the data.