# View the output of Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

I'm attempting to look at the XML output by Adam Mechanic's sp_WhoIsActive stored procedure.

When I use a typical XML editor, all I see is the raw XML.  I'd like to be able to view the graphical execution plan the way it's shown in SQL Server Management Studio when you run a query including the actual execution plan.

I'm looking at the sample actual query plan demonstrated by [Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/) and want to see that style of plan on my own queries.

Comment: I've re-worded this question to avoid it being closed as a "shopping list" request.

Comment: You can find some suggestions in the comments and my answer to this [unrelated question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103915/how-to-interpret-this-xml-plan-fragment)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a product which *understands* that the `XML` **represents** a SQL Server execution plan.

Make sure you're using the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (v17.5 as of this post) and, when you click the `XML` for the plan returned by `sp_whoisactive`, you should get an extra window showing the execution plan in graphical representation.

I'd strongly suggest downloading the latest version of [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) which is now completely free.  The latest version has SSMS add-in support such that, when you see the graphical plan in SSMS, you can right-click and choose 'View with SentryOne Plan Explorer' from the context menu and the execution plan will be displayed in SentryOne Plan Explorer. See the SentryOne post [Announcing Plan Explorer Add-In Support for SSMS 2016](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/plan-explorer-add-in-ssms-2016/).